# Jquery attribute change after hover of Fontawesome Pro only work once

Tags: jquery, font-awesome-5

Trying to create a simple rating system on hover with Fontawesome Pro. Basically when hover should show solid stars on all previous icons and light on all next.

```
<div id="ratings" class="panel-body">
  <h1>Ratings</h1>
  <i class="fal fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fal fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fal fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fal fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fal fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

and jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ratings svg").hover(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.nextAll().attr('data-prefix','fal');
      $this.prevUntil("h1").attr('data-prefix','fas');
      $this.attr('data-prefix','fas');
    });
});
```

It works once and stop right after first change. Also tried removing `attr` before, but still no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ratings svg").hover(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.nextAll().removeAttr('data-prefix','fas').attr('data-prefix','fal');
      $this.prevUntil("h1").removeAttr('data-prefix','fal').attr('data-prefix','fas');
      $this.removeAttr('data-prefix','fal').attr('data-prefix','fas');
    });
});
```

Comment: you seem to select `#ratings svg` when the icons should be selected with `#ratings i`

Comment: can you please add your code into snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Fontawesome Pro, you have to put the `<i>` inside a `span`

```
<div id="ratings" class="panel-body">
  <h1>Ratings</h1>
  <span><i class="fal fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <span><i class="fal fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <span><i class="fal fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <span><i class="fal fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <span><i class="fal fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>
```

and target the `svg` inside the `span`

```
$("#ratings span").hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.nextAll().find('svg').attr('data-prefix','fal');
    $this.prevUntil("h1").find('svg').attr('data-prefix','fas');
    $this.find('svg').attr('data-prefix','fas');
});
```